# Rank based on average score per group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
  Group  Score
    1      3
    1      2
    2      3
    2      1
    3      0
    3      1
    4      1
    4      1
```

I want to take the average score of each group and rank all groups based on the average score in descending order.

My initial thought process is to do groupby on the group column and find the average of the score column, but I am not sure what the next steps will be

Comment: `df.groupby('Group')['Score'].mean().rank()`?

Comment: Should groups with the same mean have the same rank? Also do you want to get the average scores for each group, or do you want the frame to stay intact and add a new rank column to the current frame?

Comment: @HenryEcker Groups with same mean will have the same rank. Average score for each group. and a new column should be created to the current frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) to get the mean values then [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas-series-rank):

```
df['Rank'] = (
    df.groupby('Group')['Score']
        .transform('mean')
        .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
        .astype(int)
)
```

`df`:

```
   Group  Score  Rank
0      1      3     1
1      1      2     1
2      2      3     2
3      2      1     2
4      3      0     4
5      3      1     4
6      4      1     3
7      4      1     3
```